# Solving a problem without using the Riemann - Roch theorem

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

I am studying elliptic curves and I faced with the concept of the divisors and Riemann Roch Theorem. My reference is " The Arithmetic of The Elliptic Curves " of Silverman .
I tried to solve one of the exercises that stats:

Let C be smooth curve and let  $ D \in Div(C) $. With out using the Riemann - Roch, Prove the following :

1 - $ L(D)$ is a $ \bar K -$vector space.

2- If $ Deg(D) \geq 0,$ then : $$ l(D) \leq deg (D) + 1 $$
 I  could solve the first part, but I can not solve the second. I was wondering if somebody helps me to prove it or give me a hint.

Comment: Do you mean $l(D)\le\deg(D)+1$?

Comment: yes. Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ has negative degree, then $l(D)=0$. So start an induction on the degree
starting with $\deg D=-1$. In general, write $D=D'+(P)$ for some point $P$.
It suffices to prove $l(D)\le l(D')+1$. Otherwise one must have $L(D)$
properly containing $l(D')$. Let $f$, $g\in L(D)-L(D')$. Then $f$ and $g$
have the same order  at $P$, and so $f-ag$ has degree at one higher
for a suitable scalar, so $f-ag\in L(D')$. This shows $\dim(L(D)/L(D'))\le1$,
that is $l(D)-L(D')\le1$.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't understand why such that "a" should   exist?

Comment: If such that "a" there exist, the proof completes!